# Does Ubuntu Livepatch updates take up disk space?

Tags: updates

I am new to Ubuntu so I am assuming Livepatch is the only option for me for updating the OS; I could be wrong.

However, with 1.9 GB of disk space available, will updates eat up memory?

Or are updates done using disk space in a different matter?

Answer (score 1):

> I am new to Ubuntu so I am assuming Livepatch is the only option for me for updating the OS

No. Live kernel patching is the process of applying security patches to a running Linux kernel without the need for a system reboot. It is not a replacement for updating your system.

> However, with 1.9 GB of disk space available, will updates eat up memory?

In due time yes. But updates tend to be patches, not complete files. If a whole file is downloaded it most times will replace another file. The largest update I saw up to now is when I just re-installed but even then 350-400 Mb is the update size. Not saying it can not be 1.9Gb at some time but that is a lot.

> Does Ubuntu Livepatch updates take up disk space?

Are you sure you are using live patch? Desktops do not use it as "up time" is not an issue for desktops and you need to [subscribe](https://ubuntu.com/livepatch) to it. Check with

```
 $ ls /sys/kernel/livepatch
 $
```

It is comes up empty livepatch is not active regardless of what settings are set.

Or look at

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I was able to check it out on the terminal and nothing happened. on the Livepatch icon, as I open it up I do see Livepatch is on. I'm planning to add a VM to my other laptop. How much memory should I give to the next guest OS if I have to worry about updates filling up space? I want to use the VM for ethical hacking.